# Split a single non-uniform column into 2-4 columns

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I have a column in a data frame that has data that is not uniform. I have a total of 150,000 entries.

For example

```
COLUMN
xxx
xxx yyy
xxx yyy zzz
xxx yyy zzz aaa
```

I'd like to take the column above and turn it into

```
COlUMN 1 Column 2 Column 3 Column 4
xxx
xxx       yyy
xxx       yyy      zzz
xxx       yyy      zzz       aaa
```

How would I go about doing that?

This is what I've tried so far

```
separate(Invoice_dataReduced,2,c("TRANSNO2","TRANSNO3","TRAN‌​SNO4"),sep = " ")
```

The `Invoice_dateReduced` is the data frame I'm working with.

Comment: `tidyr::separate(df, COLUMN, paste0('col', 1:4), fill = 'right')` perhaps, though this is usually a bad idea

Comment: @DavidStockinger I've tried this ... separate(Invoice_dataReduced,2,c("TRANSNO2","TRANSNO3","TRANSNO4"),sep = " "). The Invoice_dateReduced is the data frame I'm working with.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your code

Comment: alistaire's solution is what I would use. It'd be interesting to know why he thinks it's usually bad. It looks fine to me.

Comment: For those interested here's my solution I came too  i=1; df=list() ## initializing a list 
for(i in 1: nrow(Invoice_dataReduced)){
  u = unlist(strsplit(Invoice_dataReduced$TRANSNO[i], ' '))
  if (length(u)>1){
    
    j = 1 ; newdf=list()
    
    for (j in 1: length(u)){
      newdf_0 = Invoice_dataReduced[ i, ]
      newdf_0$TRANSNO = u[j]
      newdf[[j]] = newdf_0
    }
    
    df[[i]] = bind_rows(newdf)
      
    
  } else {df[[i]] = Invoice_dataReduced[ i, ]} 
  cat( i, '\n' )
}